# ASP.NET Identity - Simplified

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-identity

Existing database model (simplified):

[image]

- 1 User can be joined to 1 or many AccessGroups.
- 1 AccessGroup can have 1 or many AccessItens.

[MSDN Says:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-2.0)

> When an identity is created it may be assigned one or more claims issued by a trusted party. A claim is a name value pair that represents what the subject is, ***not what the subject can do***.

It does not seem like a good idea to store AccessItems as UserClaims,

e.g:

- **UserClaims** -> Name = CanDeleteSale; Value = True

But on the other hand I can't think another way to do that.

After search a lot, I can't think how to represent this model using roles or claims in ASP.NET Identity.

**Why?**

- Admin users can customize **AccessGroups**, then use declarative roles does not fits in this case.
- I can only trust in **AccessItens** because they are fixed Id's like enums, so I would like to use declarative auth with this using enums.
- I need to store all user **AccessItems** after user login and use it for auth actions latter, using declarative way.

ASP.NET Identity seems beautifull to me, I'm trying to understand it better now.

Sorry if I could't express my question in a clear way, please, tell me about any doubt.

Comment: Have you tried loading the AccessItems as claims _after_ authentication?  You can cache them so you're not hitting the db on each request.

Comment: It was my first idea, but I think I would be using the framework incorrectly, see what MSDN says: "A claim is a name value pair that represents what the subject is, not what the subject can do."

Answer (score 2):

I think you are on the right track. I have a lot of experience representing User Roles like this and my personal preference (I deal mostly with large enterprise projects) is to use ASP.NET identity for authentication and handling the access control with custom code.

For smaller projects I believe you can customize the IsUserInRole method like I have done below.

```
public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a list of roles assigned to a particular User
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="UserID">ID of the User</param>
    /// <param name="context">DbContext</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<string> GetUserRoles(int UserID, UserContext context)
    {
        return context.UserList
                      .Where(s => s.UserID == UserID)
                      .SelectMany(s => s.AccessGroup.GroupRoles)
                      .Select(gr => gr.RoleID.ToString()).ToList();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a list of roles assigned to a particular user
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="username">username of the user [or "" for current user]</param>
    /// <param name="context">DbContext</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<string> GetUserRoles(string username, UserContext context)
    {
        return context.UserList
                      .Where(s => s.Username == username)
                      .SelectMany(s => s.AccessGroup.GroupRoles)
                      .Select(gr => gr.RoleID.ToString()).ToList();
    }

    //roleName = RoleId; so that only the IDs are stored in session...
    public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
    {
        return GetUserRoles(username, new UserContext()).Contains<string>(roleName);
    }

    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        return GetUserRoles(username, new UserContext()).ToArray();
    }

    public override string[] GetAllRoles()
    {
        return new UserContext().UserRoleList.Select(r => r.RoleID.ToString()).ToArray();
    }

    public override bool RoleExists(string roleName)
    {
        return new UserContext().UserRoleList.Where(r => r.RoleID.ToString().Equals(roleName)).Count() > 0;
    }

    public override string ApplicationName
    {
        get { return "Your Application Name"; }
        set { }
    }

    public override string[] GetUsersInRole(string roleName)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override string[] FindUsersInRole(string roleName, string usernameToMatch)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void CreateRole(string roleName)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool DeleteRole(string roleName, bool throwOnPopulatedRole)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void RemoveUsersFromRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple using @Enoch, tks for reply. I like your idea but I would like to better understand the framework for using a cached strategy, such as loading the user's permissions at login time instead of loading on each request.

Comment: @ViniciusGonçalves You can create a string that contains the role ids that are assigned to the user e.g. "1,3,4,7,9" in your login method. Store this string in a session variable and then retrieve it when you need to perform authentication for a page. Use `var roleIDs = Session["RoleIDs"].ToString(); bool isPermitted = roleIDs.Split(',').Contains("1");` to check if the user has the right permission.